# Composer ignoring $COMPOSER_HOME

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, composer-php

I set the environment variable for composer, but it still installed to the default dir (~/.composer). Can anyone tell me if I did something wrong?

```
distPoint /var/www/html/laravel # COMPOSER_HOME="/opt/composer/"
distPoint /var/www/html/laravel # echo $COMPOSER_HOME
/opt/composer/
distPoint /var/www/html/laravel # composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
Changed current directory to /root/.composer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/process (v2.6.6)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing symfony/console (v2.6.6)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (2.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.2.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing laravel/installer (v1.2.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log (For using the console logger)
guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing ext-curl (Guzzle will use specific adapters if cURL is present)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
distPoint /var/www/html/laravel # ls ~/.composer/
cache  composer.json  composer.lock  vendor
distPoint /var/www/html/laravel # ls /opt/composer/
distPoint /var/www/html/laravel #
```

Comment: You need to `export` the environment variable as well. Otherwise the subprocess won't see it. (For instance `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is exported per default, because that's what platform-compliant tools use these days.)

Answer (score 4):

Use this inseead:

```
export COMPOSER_HOME=/opt/composer
```

It makes the variable available to sub-processes.